# In plotly (python) - is it possible to put subplots inside subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

In plotly (python) - Is it possible to create custom/subplots inside other subplots?

Otherwise, if I want to add some custom text/annotation over my subplots - can it be done?

Comment: Did you checked [here](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) yet ?

Comment: I know that the information is out there. Read it ... Just that it seemed to me intuitive that plotly with all it's powers will support recursive plots inside plots - in an object oriented manner... It does not, which is okay... I just left the question here + answer to save someone else the confusion and search for it.

Answer (score 0):

While it DOES seem intuitive for anyone coming from QT or the WEB (HTML), or any other application layout scheme (Android/WPA/...) that you can create recursive subplots inside other subplots, plotly works in somewhat different way:

There is one "sub"-plot which you need to define up front types/columns/rows - which can be a bit annoying at first, but is flexible enough to hold any grid like structure, supporting flexible cell/row spanning, but there's a learning curve...

The way to start is to look at their subplot examples here:
https://plotly.com/python/mixed-subplots/